# How to create a CloudFormation template for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

How to create CloudFormation template for setting up WordPress on one instance and MySQL on another EC2 instance?

I used this part for MySQL, but doesn't work, please give a suggestion... thank you.

```
"DatabaseServer" : {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Metadata" : {
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
  "config" : {
    "packages" : {
    "yum" : {
       "mysql"        : [],
               "mysql-server" : [],
               "mysql-devel"  : [],
               "mysql-libs"   : []
    }
    }   
  },

 "services" : {
      "sysvinit" : {  
            "mysqld"   : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" }
          }
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 4):

[AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) offers a large list or sample [AWS CloudFormation Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/), which you can start/test easily from the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/). There are several MySQL based solutions available, including a dedicated one for WordPress as well as a generic LAMP stack, in particular:

- WordPress is web software you can use to create a beautiful website or blog.

  - [Single EC2 Instance with local MySQL database](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/WordPress_Single_Instance.template)
  - [wordpress-via-cfn-bootstrap.template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/wordpress-via-cfn-bootstrap.template) - **one EC2 instance and one RDS instance**
  - Several others for usage with an SCM solution like Chef/Puppet/...
- A simple LAMP stack running a PHP "Hello World" application.

  - [Single EC2 Instance with local MySQL database](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/LAMP_Single_Instance.template)
  - [Single EC2 Instance web server with Amazon RDS database instance](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/LAMP_Single_Instance_With_RDS.template)
  - [Highly Available Web Server with Multi-AZ Amazon RDS Instance](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/LAMP_Multi_AZ.template)

I recommend to explore the selected template(s) and continue from there by tailoring it to your needs, e.g. by splitting the single EC2 instance into two (though I'd highly recommend to use a solution based on an [Amazon RDS for MySQL](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) database instead, which is much more robust and easier to handle for starters, for only slightly increased cost).

Answer (score 2):

To create a MySQL RDS instance with CFN you need to use the resource `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` with `mysql` engine and the wanted `EngineVersion`. There are some others props that you need to initialize that are not specific for MySQL Instance.
You can use [Altostra Designer](https://app.altostra.com/playground?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=first_phase&utm_medium=qnalink) to create the CFN template super quick.